# DataError in SQL insert

Tags: python, mysql-python

I can't insert some text to sql and I want to know how to process the string so it is accepted.

Editing the json file is not possible as it is too large.

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 28, in main
    cursor.execute("""insert into test_table (text) values (%s)""", (text,))
  File "../dependencies/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 507, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "../dependencies/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 722, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "../dependencies/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 640, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1366 (22007): Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x88\x922: ...' for column 'text' at row 1
```

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../dependencies'))
import json
import mysql.connector

def get_value_from_key(row, key):
    return row.get(key)

def main():
    json_path = "test.json"

    db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user='root', password='root')
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    db_name = 'test'
    cursor.execute("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS " + db_name)
    cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE " + db_name)
    cursor.execute("USE " + db_name)
    json_data = json.load(open(json_path, 'r'))

    cursor.execute("""create table test_table (id integer AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY (id),
                                               text text);""")
    db_connection.commit()
    text = get_value_from_key(json_data, "text")
    cursor.execute("""insert into test_table (text) values (%s)""", (text,))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

test.json

```
{
    "text": "+1: Create a 1/1 black Vampire creature token with lifelink.\n−2: You get an emblem with \"Creatures you control get +1/+0.\"\n−6: Destroy up to three target creatures and/or other planeswalkers. Return each card put into a graveyard this way to the battlefield under your control."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just this

```
cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE " + db_name + " DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8")
```